# Books or papers recommendation on orbifold and CFT

Tags: string-theory, differential-geometry, resource-recommendations, conformal-field-theory

Could you recommend some references on orbifold CFT?

I have found this paper "The conformal field theory of orbifolds"(1987)(http://inspirehep.net/record/230342) is very useful for me, so I want to know more about early works or reviews related to those topics.

Comment: Maybe this one is useful: https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.cmp/1104178892

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/149468/2451 and links therein.

Comment: @MengCheng, thank you! I think this paper is useful for me.